# Converting Binary to Decimal using a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

trying to convert binary to decimal using a while loop. I've done this much but the code seems to be just adding all the inputted 1s, i.e 1101011 = 5. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Cheers.

Edit: To be clear, I know I can use simpler methods, but getting the answer is unimportant, trying to develop a while loops algorithm specifically.

```
import sys
binary = sys.argv[1]
answer = 0
currentDigit = 0
currentPower = len(binary) - 1

while currentPower >= 0:
   placeHolder = int(binary[currentDigit])
   answer = answer + (placeHolder ** currentPower)
   currentDigit += 1
   currentPower -= 1

print answer
```

Answer (score 1):

A `1` in the n'th place should represent 2<sup>n</sup>, not 1<sup>n</sup>.

```
answer = answer + (placeHolder ** currentPower)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
               this is 1 in your code
```

Hopefully you can see what to fix.

Answer (score 0):

if you suffix `0b` with binary in shell, it will give you decimal

```
>>> 0b111
7
```

Another way other than `int`:

```
>>> def my_bin_dec(x):
...     return eval("{:s}".format('0b' +x))
... 
>>> my_bin_dec('111')
7
```

> Note: `eval` is unsafe to use, but you can use `ast.literal_eval`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
answer = answer + (placeHolder ** currentPower)
```

to:

```
answer = answer + placeHolder * 2 ** currentPower
```

or more concisely:

```
answer += placeHolder * 2 ** currentPower
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it using a while loop. This performs a left shift on the running value and then adds 1 if the bit is a 1:

```
binary = '11001101101010101'
value = 0
i = 0
while i < len(binary):
    value <<= 1    # Shift left 1 bit position. Same as multiplying by 2.
    value += (binary[i] == '1')
    i += 1

assert value == int(binary, 2)
```

It's even simpler (and slightly faster) with a for loop:

```
binary = '11001101101010101'
value = 0
for bit in binary:
    value <<= 1
    value += (bit == '1')

assert value == int(binary, 2)
```

Finally, it is possible to do it in one line. At the cost of code readability this seems to be faster than the loops above:

```
value = sum([(1<<i) if bit=='1' else 0 for i,bit in enumerate(reversed(binary))])
```